# Can't set environment variables from yaml file

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml

I was using `environ` to set my environment variables but now i need to change to a `yml` file.
I've made a function to open my `yml` file and load it, i think here everything is working fine.
Then in my `__init__.py` i use the function, passed the path to the `yml` file and then use `app.config.from_object(data)`to load the environment variables to the system.
The problem is that the environment variables that i set in the yml file are not being used by the app, because i got an error saying that my `LDAPUSERNAME` cannot be None.

This was my config.py using environ:

```
LDAP_BASE_DN = os.environ.get('LDAP_BASE_DN', default= "dc=planetexpress,dc=com")
LDAP_USERNAME = os.environ.get('LDAP_USERNAME', default="CN=Hermes Conrad,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com")
LDAP_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('LDAP_PASSWORD', default="hermes")
```

This is my yml file that i want to use:

```
LDAP_BASE_DN: 'dc=planetexpress,dc=com'
LDAP_USERNAME: 'CN=Hermes Conrad,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com'
LDAP_OPENLDAP: 'yes'
```

yaml_loader.py

```
from yaml import load, Loader, dump, Dumper



def yaml(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as stream:

        data_loaded = load(stream, Loader=Loader)

        return data_loaded
```

**init**.py

```
app.config.from_object('dev_maintenance.config')---> "used to load the environ"

data = yaml_loader.yaml("/Users/pjose/Project/dev_maintenance/backend/config.yml")
app.config.from_object(data) ---> using now to load the yml
```

It's not working, i don't know why
Any help?

Comment: In your new code there is no longer a call to `.os.environ`, so why would you expect the environment to be changed? You'll need to set that for each of the key/value pairs in `data_loaded` yourself. Apart from that, [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is not the same as [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` at least since Sep 2006.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the environment entries yourself based on the key-value pairs of the 
loaded `data`:

```
import os
from yaml import load, Loader


yaml_str = """\
LDAP_BASE_DN: dc=planetexpress,dc=com
LDAP_USERNAME: CN=Hermes Conrad,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com
LDAP_OPENLDAP: 'yes'
"""

data = load(yaml_str, Loader=Loader)
for k in data:
    os.environ[k] = data[k]
```

Please note that you need to quote `yes`, as PyYAML, still only implements the
YAML 1.1 specification (which has been outdated for over ten years) otherwise
it will see `yes` as a boolean. The other quotes however are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Anthon, but i don't want to use environ. Usually i would set this variables like this `app.config['LDAP_USERNAME'] = 'CN=user,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=org'` where i have the code that use them.With environ i could get them and set to default. Now i just want to use a yaml file that sets this variables to been use on the app. I've seen examples that they declare this variables like me in the yaml file, but i don't know how they make the app use them.

Comment: @PatrickJosé If that is going to work, then it is something that is done outside of PyYAML by the application that is possible using PyYAML to load its values. Without knowing that application it is guesswork what you might need to do. (it could e.g. be that the key-value pairs should be under some root level key `environ:`)